# Is there a list of simplified Chinese radicals?

Tags: simplified-characters, resources, radicals

Is there a list of simplified Chinese radicals? The radical 159 车 consists of 7 strokes, in fact it is its traditional version 車 which includes 7 strokes ...

Answer (score 1):

I think there's quite a few around.  My favorite is [Search by Radical](https://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/sinograms.html?r) at chinese-tools.com.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

([Stack Exchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycZwn.png) version of the image.)

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to Table II of *Final Table of Simplified Characters* ([简化字总表](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hans/%E7%AE%80%E5%8C%96%E5%AD%97%E6%80%BB%E8%A1%A8)) for 14 simplified radicals. Although the table itself has been replaced since 2013, it is the only official reference for simplified Chinese radicals.

Answer (score 1):

A complete list of radicals is easily available in a regular dictionary. It’s usually placed at the very beginning of the dictionary, including all radicals. No matter which one you are looking for, you’ll be able to find it. 
For example this one. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of Chinese radicals, including both simplified and traditional versions. 
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical